# Karma Kanda & Jnana Kanda

Tags: vedas, karma, jnana

In the Vedas there are two paths mentioned Karma Kanda & Jnana Kanda. First one goes through Karma and then one comes to Jnana.

At the same time it's often mentioned that there are also the paths of Bhakti & Raja.

If we look closer they're part of the Karma or Janna practices. However some people don't see it like this and say either one of those can bring you to the goal.

Could someone clarify this?

Comment: The karmakanda refers to the samhita and brahmana portions of the vedas that teach sacrifices to attain good karma in thie world and the next. They promise rebirth. The jnanakanda refers to the portion of the vedas called the Upanishads which teach how to attain God and escape this endless round of birth and rebirth. You do not need to do the karmakanda before going to the jnanakanda. If you have a sincere desire to attain God, then you can skip the karmakanda entirely. Karma Yoga should not be confused with Karmakanda, they are two entirely different animals.

Answer (score 1):

As no explicit question is asked, I assume that the question is this: Are Bhakti Yoga and Raja Yoga part of either Gnana Yoga or Karma Yoga? No, they are not:

> *Bhakti Yoga: The Path of Devotion*
>
> God's love is unconditional. Acknowledging that
> love and reflecting it back is devotion. The blossoming of devotion
> towards God is the sweetest experience one can have.
>
> Devotion means being in a state of complete surrender to God. It is
> the desire to serve God, accompanied by love and gratitude. A devotee
> sees Divinity everywhere and yet has an intense longing for the
> Divine. Bhakti Yoga is one of the types of yoga mentioned in the
> ancient Indian scripts which denotes the spiritual practice of
> lovingly devoting oneself to a personal form of God. Bhakti is a
> Sanskrit term for devotion.
>
> Love towards God can take many forms with many different feelings: A
> true friendship with God, being a faithful servant to God, being a
> beloved of God, being a child of God, being a parent to God.
>
> In
> devotion, one can experience total freedom from fear and worry. A
> devotee transcends worldly sorrows and pains.
>
> A true devotee has no selfish desires, including the desire for
> liberation. Devotion in one's heart is kindled by the grace of the
> Guru, by being in the company of other devotees and by reading and
> listening to the stories of other devotees.
>
> “When the river meets the ocean, it recognizes it is the ocean from
> the beginning to the end. In the same way, the moment a devotee
> surrenders to the Divine, the devotee becomes Divine.”

The above is from an article by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: http://www.artofliving.org/in-en/bhakti-yoga

Also, *Raja Yoga* is different. Also called the Path of the Royals, it is the path of knowledge that was given to highly evolved kings. A lot of secrets are given which are only meant for the ruler and not the common people. Hence, not much is talked about this.